# Adding data to highstocks by pushing array

Tags: javascript, asp.net, highcharts

Been struggling to get my data right from the array to the chart. This is my code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "<%=ResolveUrl("Services/HighstockService.asmx/TempData") %>",
            data: "{}", /* Sending specific indata */
            dataType: "json",           
            success: function (Result) {
                //debugger;
                Result = Result.d;
                var tempData = [];
                for (var i in Result) {
                    var serie = new Array("[" + parseInt(Result[i].Date.substr(6)) + "," + Result[i].Value + "],");
                    tempData.push(serie);
                }
                DrawTempChart(tempData);
            },
            error: function (Result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }); 
    function DrawTempChart(tempData) {
        debugger;
        $('#tempChart').highcharts('StockChart', {
            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                second: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                minute: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
                hour: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
                day: '%Y %m-%d',
                week: '%Y %m-%d',
                month: '%Y-%m',
                year: '%Y'
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'AAPL',
                data: [tempData],
            }]
        });
    }
</script>
```

I am adding the brackets and comma to every index in the array to follow the structure of how highstocks accepts data. When debugging, I then receive data like this: "[1418017375000,33],".

I need to parseInt the Date due to javascript adding parenthesis and forward slashes when moving it from Web Services. I am unsure if it gets rightly formatted in the javascript to work in the chart.

Since I really can't debug the DrawTempChart function, I don't actually know how the array is sent into that function. Anyone that can see what I am doing wrong?

[edit] Should probably be added that the closest I have come to an output is to show only the last index in the array on the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `data` in `series` should be like this:

```
[[UTCTime1, value1], [UTCTime2, value2], ...]
```

So change the line `data: [tempData]` to this:

```
data: tempData
```

Second, when you are creating a new `Array`, the format is not this:

```
var serie = new Array("[" + parseInt(Result[i].Date.substr(6)) + "," + Result[i].Value + "],");
```

You should write it this way:

```
var serie = new Array(parseInt(Result[i].Date.substr(6)), Result[i].Value);
```

and it will automatically add the `[]` and `,` : `[item1, item2]`

When you push `serie` into `tempData` it will also put `,` between items.

At last, be sure that `Result[i].Date.substr(6)` creates correct and sorted 13 digits UTC numbers because highcharts doesn't sort the data.

Comment: Wow... Been so close all the time and the problem from start was the "data: tempData". Now it's working! 

Love you bro! No Homo ;)